# Will it ruin a blower's future-adjustments to do the 'H & L screw-hack'?

Tags: small-engine

These 2-strokes have H & L adjustments on the carbs but often have limiters built in and commonly people just hack a line across them to adjust with a flat-head, I'm tempted to do this *but*, at the same time, almost every-last-unit I own (from blowers to saws to everything) seems to have the same *type* of splined-adjustment threading, am getting the impression it's just *1* tool (not 1 tool - per - brand!) in which case it seems you can order them from china for $1 and using a saw on such a delicate part of your carb would just be foolish!
Thanks :)

Comment: The H and L adjustment screws are simply screws with a pointed end that move in and out of openings in the carburetor and adjust the amount of air fed to the motor at (L - idle) and (H - high RPM/wide open). There is no magic to adjustment. It will be in your manual, but generically, start by closing (screwing them in) all the way and then back out 1 and 1/2 or 1 and 3/4 revolutions. Start the engine, adjust the L in/out until you have the desired idle, then squeeze the trigger (accelerator) and turn the H in/out until it accelerates from idle smoothly and runs smooth wide-open.

Answer (score 0):

All the older chainsaws I had, had flat head adjusting screws fitted as standard...

So, your choice : cut the heads or order the tool. Ordering the tool will mean not having to take the screws out, which may be a good thing.